# Отслеживать выключение

Tags: android

Есть ли какой-либо бродкаст ресивер, чтобы отследить выключение устройства?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [How receive device shutdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984439/receive-android-device-shutdown)
- [Is there any way to get a notice when a user power off their Android phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190126/is-there-any-way-to-get-a-notice-when-a-user-power-off-their-android-phone/2190184#2190184)

Comment: 2ая ссылка очень помогла. Спс.